# Why the first actual parameter printing as a output in C

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int add(int a, int b)
{
    if (a > b)
        return a * b;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", add(3, 7));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

In the above code, I am calling the function inside the print. In the function, the `if` condition is not true, so it won't execute. Then why I am getting 3 as output? I tried changing the first parameter to some other value, but it's printing the same when the `if` condition is not satisfied.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: What value do you return if a <= b?

Comment: For a starter: Enable all compiler warnings, and *fix* them.

Answer (score 2):

What happens here is called *undefined behaviour*.

When `(a <= b)`, you don't return any value (and your compiler probably told you so). But if you use the return value of the function anyway, even if the function doesn't return anything, that value is garbage. In your case it is 3, but with another compiler or with other compiler flags it could be something else.

If your compiler didn't warn you, add the corresponding compiler flags. If your compiler is `gcc` or `clang`, use the `-Wall` compiler flags.

Answer (score 1):

Jabberwocky is right: this is undefined behavior. You should turn your compiler warnings on and listen to them.

However, I think it can still be interesting to see what the compiler was thinking. And we have a tool to do just that: [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/).

We can plug your C program into Godbolt and see what assembly instructions it outputs. Here's the [direct Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/YK5sKfdz4), and here's the assembly that it produces.

```
add:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        jle     .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        jmp     .L1
.L2:
.L1:
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "%d"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     esi, 7
        mov     edi, 3
        call    add
        mov     esi, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Again, to be *perfectly* clear, what you've done is undefined behavior. With different compiler flags or a different compiler version or even just a compiler that happens to feel like doing things differently on a particular day, you will get different behavior. What I'm studying here is the assembly output by gcc 12.2 on Godbolt with optimizations disabled, and I am **not** representing this as standard or well-defined behavior.

This engine is using the [System V AMD64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI), common on Linux machines. In System V, the first two integer or pointer arguments are passed in the `rdi` and `rsi` registers, and integer values are returned in `rax`. Since everything we work with here is either an `int` or a `char*`, this is good enough for us. Note that the compiler seems to have been smart enough to figure out that it only needs `edi`, `esi`, and `eax`, the lower half-words of each of these registers, so I'll start using `edi`, `esi`, and `eax` from this point on.

Our main function works fine. It does everything we'd expect. Our two function calls are here.

```
mov     esi, 7
mov     edi, 3
call    add
mov     esi, eax
mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
mov     eax, 0
call    printf
```

To call `add`, we put `3` in the `edi` register and `7` in the `esi` register and then we make the call. We get the return value back from `add` in `eax`, and we move it to `esi` (since it will be the *second* argument to `printf`). We put the address of the static memory containing `"%d"` in `edi` (the first argument), and then we call `printf`. This is all normal. `main` knows that `add` was declared to return an integer, so it has the right to assume that, after calling `add`, there will be something useful in `eax`.

Now let's look at `add`.

```
add:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        jle     .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        imul    eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        jmp     .L1
.L2:
.L1:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

The `rbp` and `rsp` shenanigans are standard function call fare and aren't specific to `add`. First, we load our two arguments onto the call stack as local variables. Now here's where the undefined behavior comes in. Remember that I said `eax` is the return value of our function. Whatever happens to be in `eax` when the function returns is the returned value.

We want to compare `a` and `b`. To do that, we need `a` to be in a register (lots of assembly instructions require their left-hand argument to be a register, while the right-hand can be a register, reference, immediate, or just about anything). So we load `a` into `eax`. Then we compare the value in `eax` to the value `b` on the call stack. If `a > b`, then the `jle` does nothing. We go down to the next two lines, which are the inside of your `if` statement. They *correctly* set `eax` and return a value.

*However,* if `a <= b`, then the `jle` instruction jumps to the end of the function without doing anything else to `eax`. Since the last thing in `eax` happened to be `a` (because we happened to use `eax` as our comparison register in `cmp`), that's what gets returned from our function.

But this really is just random. It's what the compiler happened to have put in that register previously. If I turn optimizations up (with `-O3`), then gcc inlines the whole function call and ends up printing out `0` rather than `a`. I don't know exactly what sequence of optimizations led to this conclusion, but since they started out by hinging on undefined behavior, the compiler is free to make what assumptions it chooses.